# RESTful API Authentication & Security

Tags: php, api, rest, security

I am developing an Android and iOS application that will use a RESTful API that I developed on a separate server. The applications will simply poke at the endpoints to update data within the database and to retrieve information when needed. My problem is not doing that, the architecture of the API is already setup I just need to think about the most secure way to implement it.

I have an API Key system that requires any uses of the API to be paired with the requests which will prevent anyone without the key from accessing the API. This works well, but I am worried about people who are more determined to break through the system. Specifically on the Android side, applications can be decompiled and (some) of the code can be viewed. I am pretty sure that strings can be viewed so I am worried that if someone decompiles the application they will get ahold of the API Key and be able to access the API.

I am looking for suggestions to make the API more secure. I have already considered pairing another unique value with the API Key when updating information but I am not sure if this will work that well either.

Any suggestions are very appreciated it.

Comment: How do you track which user  makes the request if you use the same key on all app users? If you issue a unique key for each user it seems like the problem you're having shouldn't really be a problem. If they somehow reverse engineer your api and use their key they will still only be allowed to do execute actions they are permitted to.

Comment: Each user will have a unique identification number which is received through another 3rd party service. Because this number could be found again in a separate application, I have the idea of creating another unique identification number, auto-generated through the database. I guess then this would be secure enough. Hm.

Comment: I'd much prefer some hash value. If a malicious user sees that their api key is 1000135 you can be sure they will try 1000136, etc.

Comment: Right, yeah a randomly generated hash value would probably work best to prevent them from just trying every positive integer. I'll try and implement this function. I'll just need to figure out a good hashing algorithm

Answer (score 0):

You are right about being worried that your application can be decompiled. Code and strings are stored in the clear. In fact this is rather trivial to do.

I've heard that someone looked at two applications: one contained email service password and username in clear text, very useful for spammers. Another had its "random" number algorithm exposed allowing hackers to generate today's "random" number and ride for free using public transport facilities.

You can raise the bar by:

- Obfuscating your code with tools. Some tools will offer capability to encrypt strings.
- Manually encrypt sensitive strings in your application using new encryption key per new install, split your encryption key and hide it in several different places, e.g. part in code, part in a database, part in OS and apply ACL to external locations
- Use transport security (e.g TLS) to reduce risk of man-in-the-middle attacks
- Use API rate limiter on the server side
- Introduce geo location services to see if same API key is used from different locations at the same time